# Display vs Visibility

Tags: html, css, visibility, hidden, display

In one of my page I can have two situation.

The first, in case no event found

```
<div class="mec-wrap mec-skin-list-container" id="mec_skin_1210">
        <div class="mec-skin-list-events-container" id="mec_skin_events_1210">
        No event found!    </div>
</div>
```

or this if at least event is found

```
<div class="mec-wrap mec-skin-list-container" id="mec_skin_1210">
      <div class="mec-skin-list-events-container" id="mec_skin_events_1210">
        <div class="mec-wrap colorskin-custom">
    <div class="mec-event-list-minimal">
            <article data-style="" class="mec-event-article mec-clear  mec-divider-toggle mec-toggle-202003-1210" itemscope="">
ARTICLE HERE
    </article>
                        </div>
</div>
        <div class="mec-skin-list-no-events-container" id="mec_skin_events_1210">
        Nessun evento trovato!    </div>
    </div>
```

I need to hidden the first situation, I don't see the "No events found"
I have found a solution with css.
This work fine, but if I use display instead visibility, the code not work.
Work fine the "display:none" but I can't make it reappear the structure if event is found.
I have tried every value for "display" (block, flex, etc. etc.) nobody works

https://codepen.io/MarcoRM69/pen/VwLrXWb

```
.mec-skin-list-events-container {  
visibility:hidden;  
}
.mec-skin-list-events-container > div {
  visibility:visible;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please try and explain a little more clearly what you need?

Comment: Hi connexo, 

I am sorry for my bad english.

I have a plugin that displays the events. The div structure is the second one.
If there are no events the plugin show "No event founds!" with the first div structure.
I not see the "No event founds!" message.

Unfortunately the plugin not have this feature and I don't edit the code because at the first upgrade lose all my modify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern browsers doesn't yet have impletemted [`has()` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) unfortunately.

You can that easily with a JavaScript or library such as jQuery instead of using CSS. jQuery implement [`:has()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/#has1).

> Description: Selects elements which contain at least one element that matches the specified selector.
>   The expression `$( "div:has(p)" )` matches a `<div>` if a `<p>` exists anywhere among its descendants, not just as a direct child.

```js
$('.mec-skin-list-events-container').addClass("d-none");
$('.mec-skin-list-events-container:has(div)').addClass("d-block");
```

```css
body {
  color: green;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.mec-skin-list-events-container+div:not(:has(div)) {
  color: black;
}

.d-none {
  display: none;
}

.d-block {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mec-wrap mec-skin-list-container" id="mec_skin_1210">
  <div class="mec-skin-list-events-container" id="mec_skin_events_1210">
    Nessun evento trovato! </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="mec-wrap mec-skin-list-container" id="mec_skin_1210">
  <div class="mec-skin-list-events-container" id="mec_skin_events_1210">
    <div class="mec-wrap colorskin-custom">
      <div class="mec-event-list-minimal">
        <article data-style="" class="mec-event-article mec-clear  mec-divider-toggle mec-toggle-202003-1210" itemscope="">
          ARTICLE HERE
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mec-skin-list-no-events-container" id="mec_skin_events_1210">
      Nessun evento trovato! </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.
Now I try your solution

Comment: @SirLancillotto If the problem is resolved, click the green check mark to the left of the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

`display: none...` is not working, while `visibility:hidden...` is working because `display: none` removes the affected element from the page while `visibility:hidden` does not.

Since `display:none` removes the containing div, you cannot then ask to display the contained div.

> From your codepen:

```
.mec-skin-list-events-container {  
  visibility:hidden; 
  /*display:none;*/

}
.mec-skin-list-events-container > div {
  visibility:visible;
  /*display:block;*/  
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know the difference
I'd rather use display: none to remove the div from the stream